# Does Cloud9 support Python’s Mako Templating filetype?

Tags: cloud9-ide, mako

I recently started trying out cloud9 IDE. My project relies on Python's Mako Templating. Before this, I use Atom Editor, which has a module to highlight syntax of Mako. When I imported the `.mako` files to Cloud9, however, it doesn't seem to be highlighted at all. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud9 does not currently support `.mako` file highlighting.

***Note***: If you're interested in implementing highlighting for a certain syntax/language, you can have a look at the [Ace documentation about this](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=higlighter) (Cloud9 uses the Ace editor) or the [Cloud9 SDK documentation](https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io/docs/highlighting-rules).

Comment: If I wait for a couple of months, do you think Cloud9 will natively support `.mako` then?

Comment: No idea :/ It's possible.